# How to browse through this site

Tags: discussion

I love to browse through bookstores. You stumble across things you had  never considered or even thought of. You find books whose existence surprises you. It's always an adventure. I'd love to do the same with this site, but HOW? How do you browse through the archives of this site? Incidentally, I have to say that the tag requirement makes this a very user unfriendly site. I had to go through 15 of your pages before I could find tags that might be acceptable. I found four. I used these four, YOUR four. Guess what? They were rejected.  I was told to use tags, or something to that effect. What do I have to do to get something posted. It can be done. Others have done it. I should be able to do it. I just can't, not, at least in four days of trying.

Comment: I finally got through. I had thought the more tags the better, but when deleted three of them, YOUR tags, I was able to post my message. I would still like to see a section of this site devoted to HOW TO USE IT.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. I sympathise with you about the condition of the site's documentation. I think the site started as a programmer's Q&A site, then grew to accommodate other topics. Documentation hasn't traditionally been something programmers are good at. Many of the people here are friendly, though - that makes up for a lot :) . If you get stuck, jump onto [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-and-usage). There are usually people around who can help.

Comment: However, bear in mind that to talk in chat [requires 20 rep points](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), which could come from just one good post on the main ELU site.

Comment: Did you look at the [help] ? You may also want to check out the [tour].  I’m a little confused about whether you were browsing or posting.

Comment: Did you look at the advanced search options (https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=help#)? Probably, but I don't want to just assume . . .

Comment: I don't understand what Warren wanted to do. (1) Look at questions that had the [tags](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags) he was interested in? (2) Write [a new question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), in which case it doesn't matter what tags were selected the system would not have rejected the question. (3) Maybe he inadvertently created "new" tags?  (4) Fifteen pages before he found tags which might have been acceptable? Acceptable for what?

Comment: Now, his question has been migrated to meta... I doubt he'll ever find it again.  :)

Comment: A breakthrough. Finally, finally, I was able to post something, and I even got a response, several, in fact. That will do for today. Tomorrow I'm going to press my luck and see what else I can do. Oh, someone mentioned Meta. Been there. Tried that. Unfortunately, it got me nowhere, but I'll try again. Now it doesn't seem so hopeless. Thanks, guys.

Comment: @WarrenJones you *are* in meta. Did you post an English language question on the main site? ...checks... The only Q  I can see is [What is the status of “natural” punctuation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/413062/what-is-the-status-of-natural-punctuation) and it was posted 7 months ago.

Comment: See my comment here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/413062/what-is-the-status-of-natural-punctuation#comment1079164_413062

Comment: Mari-Lou,That's because things I had thought were posted were not. There were only a couple, though. No loss. Thanks for telling me that I'm in meta. It doesn't feel any different, though.

Comment: The ELU site is part of the StackExchange network of Q&A sites. Each site has the same basic template, with graphical tweaks on most sites. Each site also has an associated meta site where questions _about_ the site (such as how it works and how the site deals with various issues that pop up—questions like this one) are posted. You originally posted this on the main Q&A site, but since it’s asking about how the site works, it was moved here, to the meta discussion site. The design here is slightly different: there’s more yellow on the main site.

Comment: As others have commented, though, the question you have asked here is not very clear. What exactly was it you were trying to do that you couldn’t get to work? Were you browsing the existing questions, or were you trying to ask a new question? At what stage did the tag thing happen? Tags are there to sort questions by topics. When you ask a new question, you have to give it some relevant tags so it can get sorted properly. You don’t have to scroll through 15 pages of tags, though: you can search instead. And when you search for questions on the site, you can also search for tags.

Comment: I keep seeing someone say that my question is unclear when it couldn't be clearer. If anyone doesn't understand my crystal-clear questions the fault lies with him, not me.  Nevertheless, being a newcomer, it is my obligation to do my best to accommodate the idiosyncrasies of the people who have been here longer than me. Nevertheless, this site oftentimes seems more like a peculiar and arcane cabal/ clique/ coterie/cell/sect than a useful forum.

Comment: @WarrenJones Your question is terribly unclear and a defensive attitude doesn't make people want to help you.